# Is there a solution to handle and maintain a JavaScript request in Server Side (Flask - Python)?

Tags: javascript, python, flask, asynchronous

I have this piece of code in JavaScript:

```
function checkUpdate() {
    setInterval(updateState, 1000, document.getElementById('serverId').textContent);
}

function updateState(serverId) {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
            const reponse = request.responseText
            if (reponse != document.getElementById('lastCommand').textContent) {
                document.getElementById('lastCommand').textContent = reponse
                eval(document.getElementById('lastCommand').textContent)
            }
        }
    }
    request.open('GET', '/updateState?serverId='+serverId, true);
    request.send(null);
}
```

and here is the Python side:

```
@app.route('/updateState')
def updateState():
    serverId = int(request.args['serverId'])
    for instance in instances:
        try:
            if serverId == instance.id: return instance.lastCommand[-1]
        except IndexError:
            return 'Error'
    return 'Error'
```

I want JavaScript to periodically request the server (Flask) to maintain a synchronization between users in a same instance of a game. The server return the last command executed by any player before. If the result of the request is not the same as it was before, then an action has been made by a player. So we make it Client-Side with JavaScript functions to synchronize. The problem is that sometimes when the request has been sent in the same time as a command was executed. Normally, the server would execute the command, then receive the request, and return the result.

But when it arrives sometimes, the server respond like if no commands were executed, like if he did not treated the command, and returns no change on the last command executed, so nothing append Client-Side because nothing changed. I precise that when the command and the request are not sent at the same time, it works fine, but with 1 second of delay for the request every time, it has a lot of chance to be in the same time.

I tried to not make JavaScript requesting every second, but requesting once, waiting for server response. And it's only when the server execute a command that it will return a response to the request. I manage to do the JavaScript Side but to make the server wait a command without interrupting Flask execution, I didn't. I tried with async function but I'm not a pro with these.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can use sockets to solve this.

Using socketio, it should look something like the following:

client:

```
socket.on('commandUpdate', (lastCommand) => {
    document.getElementById('lastCommand').textContent = lastCommand
    eval(document.getElementById('lastCommand').textContent)
})
```

flask server:

```
from flask_socketio import emit

@app.route('/updateState')
def updateState():
  emit('commandUpdate', request.args['lastCommand'])
```

I would also read online on socketio to set up the connection between your client and server.

Hope this helps.

Comment: With a little of adjustements, a made it work, Thanks !